# Any other way than using ofstream to write data to .txt files in C++

Tags: c++, omnet++

I tried to use `ofstream` to write data to a .txt file in OMNET++ as follows with `iostream` and `fstream` included:

```
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open ("example.txt");
myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
myfile.close();
```

But OMNET++ is not resolving `open` and `close` functions.

Can someone suggest any way other than `ofstream` to achieve the same task of reading and writing data to .txt files in C++?

Comment: fopen/fprintf/fclose should be always there to save your bacon :-)

Comment: "But OMNET++ is not resolving open and close functions." - what do you mean by that? Compiler errors?

Comment: Does fopen/fprint/fclose work with C++ as well or you can use them only in C?

Comment: of course it does, why not?

Comment: What kind of a C++ implementation doesn't support the C++ standard library? Does it happen if you correctly qualify the identifiers (e.g. `std::ofstream myfile;`)?

Comment: @H2CO3: It is not able to find header files to resolve open and close functions. Yes compiler error.

Comment: Thank you @Angew. It worked std::ofstream myfile;. I would have tried it before :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Turning my comment into an answer.*

`ofstream` (and all other Standard Library classes) are defined in namespace `std`. You need to use qualified names (such as `std::ofstream`) to access them.